# Not able to print contribution invoice

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, invoice, user-dashboard

CMS: Drupal 7

CiviCRM: 4.7.31

"*CiviCRM: access Contact Dashboard*" permission is set for authenticated user and logged in user has "*CiviCRM: view my invoices*" permission also.

User can access contact dashboard page with buttons to print invoice for contributions but get access denied message unless "*CiviContribute: access CiviContribute*" permission is also assigned to user role.

[image]

Comment: I don't see civipay permissions on the site i checked. is this an extension?

Comment: I found this because I also was alerted to this same (?) problem from a Joomla registered user today. Civi 4.7.27, do not have CiviPay extension. User can access her dashboard with Print Invoice buttons, but gets permission error when trying to access them. "CiviCRM: view my invoices" is allowed for Joomla Registered Users.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, CiviPay = CiviContribute. I will update my original question.

Answer (score 3):

To print invoice the user should either have access CiviContribute or view my invoice permission. "CiviPay: access CiviPay" permission doesn't come with CiviCRM install. I feel CiviPay extension might be conflicting with Print invoice as the extension may be using same url as of print invoice i.e `civicrm/contribute/invoice`.

Pradeep

Comment: Sorry my bad, CiviContribute was renamed to CiviPay on the site i was testing. 'view my invoice permission' is assigned to role but still user cannot view invoices unless 'CiviContribute: access CiviContribute' is also given.

Comment: My exerience is the same as Hassan's: "CiviContribute: access CiviContribute" is required for front-end users to access the invoices. Related question: Does giving this access to front end users create any vulnerabilities to the data? Is there a risk of people accessing more than I might expect?

Comment: The code say that the link is accessible to any user with Access CiviContribute user or logged in user with 'view my invoice' to view their own invoice. I just tried and i could download the pdf with 'view my invoice' permission. User having 'view my invoice' permission won't be allowed to download invoice of other contact.