# Wordpress Civicrm doesn't seem to generate invoice from other user roles except administrator

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civicrm-home

CMS: Wordpress 4.9.6

CiviCRM: 5.2.1

I'm trying to generate Invoice with the below url, Which is working fine when I login as administrator. but when I login as actual member to download Invoice from WordPress front end with the same url giving me this error

```
  Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

( I gave this civi permission

```
CiviCRM: view my invoices 
Allow users to view/ download their own invoices
```

to all user roles).
[image]

```
http://devsri.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/invoice&reset=1&id=48657&cid=35509
```

Its working when I give below(CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API)permission

```
"CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API" Master control for access to the main CiviCRM backend and API. Give to trusted roles only.
```

[image]

But I cant give this permission to a member just to download Invoice. In drupal its working with "CiviCRM: view my invoices" permission. I wonder if its a bug in Civi Wordpress??

Did anyone experience this? or Am I missing anything here?

TIA

Comment: Probably this link(https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/not-able-to-print-contribution-invoice) might help you. HTH
Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, but "View my invoices" permission is enabled for my wordpress. In drupal I tried it with the same permissoin, its working fine on drupal. I feel its a wordpress issue. I tried to check "mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Task/Invoice.php" file, its not coming to "public static function getPrintPDF" function. seems wordpress permissions is having some issue in civi.

Comment: I think you will provide access civicrm permission.

Comment: Or you can try http://devsri.mywebsite.com/default-civipage?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/invoice&reset=1&id=48657&cid=35509

Comment: I'm getting this error after change url."The requested URL /default-civipage was not found on this server."

Comment: Its working after giving this permission "CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API"
Master control for access to the main CiviCRM backend and API. Give to trusted roles only. But I cant give this permission to a member. In drupal it is not required

Comment: default-civipage is something that is set under http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem here. actually there is some issue with CiviCRM Wordpress codebase because its always failing to get wordpress user id.

Below checkDownloadInvoice function using drupal `global $user;` to get logged in user id for wordpress as well.

```
CRM_Core_Permission::checkDownloadInvoice

public static function checkDownloadInvoice() {
    global $user;
    $cid = CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::getContactId($user->uid);
    if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('access CiviContribute') ||
      (CRM_Core_Permission::check('view my invoices') && $_GET['cid'] == $cid)
    ) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
```

for WordPress It should be changed to

```
public static function checkDownloadInvoice() {
    $uid = get_current_user_id();//changed for WordPress
    $cid = CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::getContactId($uid);//changed for WordPress
    if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('access CiviContribute') ||
      (CRM_Core_Permission::check('view my invoices') && $_GET['cid'] == $cid)
    ) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
```

Hope it helps someone in future. :)

Comment: You should put this in the issue queue